# About Encoding when read file .txt in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to import a text file to R. I used encoding "UTF-8".

```
df1 <- read.delim(path, sep = ",", header = F, colClasses = "character", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I want to filter rows that have "QUẢNG CÁO GIỮA 2 CHƯƠNG TRÌNH". But there is no row. 
I have tried some codes:

```
df1$V10[1]
[1] "QUẢNG CÁO GIỮA 2 CHƯƠNG TRÌNH"
```

When I run:

```
df1$V10[1] == "QUẢNG CÁO GIỮA 2 CHƯƠNG TRÌNH"
[1] FALSE
```

I don't understand why is false?

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: df1$V10[1]  ==>  [1] "QUẢNG CÁO GIỮA 2 CHƯƠNG TRÌNH" . When run df1$V10[1] == "QUẢNG CÁO GIỮA 2 CHƯƠNG TRÌNH"  == > [1] FALSE

Comment: Is your R-Studio also set to UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Yes, my Rstudio is setting UTF-8.

Comment: The comparison does work fine in my environment and with data copy&pasted form your question. So either somethig is different in your R-enviroment (encoding) or my test data is not identical to yours. I created a minimal csv file to read and this is the hexdum of it:
`00000000  51 55 e1 ba a2 4e 47 20  43 c3 81 4f 20 47 49 e1  |QU...NG C..O GI.|`

`00000010  bb ae 41 20 32 20 43 48  c6 af c6 a0 4e 47 20 54  |..A 2 CH....NG T|`

`00000020  52 c3 8c 4e 48 2c 20 66  6f 6f 0a                 |R..NH, foo.|`
Maybe you can show us a hexdump, too?

Comment: Hi Mr Phil, I am using windows, and I do not know how to show hexdump like you example. :(. I would like share you my data that I am working.

Comment: How do I attach a text file in stackoverflow? :D

Comment: I don't think you can attach data, unfortunately. You could upload it somewhere else but then the data will probably go away at some point so the question becomes obsolete here... I believe windows has a power-shell command `format-hex` – that should do it.

Comment: And the output of `Encoding(df1$V10[1])` could be helpful as well as the `Encoding` of the string typed in directly in R.